# Rule for Waw with dagesh or not?

Tags: hebrew, grammar, syntax

I'm reading through my Hebrew. And I'm bumping into waws with dageshes in the middle of them and others without.  Way back in class I remember that there was a rule for this. But I can't remember what it was.  So my question is this: *What is the rule for whether a waw gets a dagesh at the front of the word or not?* Even more helpful would be a paragraph/section reference in JM or GKC or Walke/O Conner where I can brush up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The וּ is called a shúreq and functions as a vowel (not a consonant).  The וּ / û vowel can appear either at the end or in the middle of a word.

When the "waw" is used as a conjunctive "waw", and is prefixed to a *bet, mem,* or *pey* consonant (BMP), it takes the form of a shureq and the subsequent consonant loses its dagesh.

See [HERE](https://www.hebrew4christians.com/Grammar/Unit_Four/Conjunctive_Vav/conjunctive_vav.html) for a nice explanation with examples.

Comment: Ahhh, the "BUMM-UFFF" rule.  Thanks for the reminder and the link.